# check if a word is in a list and count it as a correct answer

Tags: python

I'm new and I have to checks if the user answers is correct and count one point if the whole line is given or just one word. i don't know how to count one word only. please help me

```
list=["one way or another"]
               
user= "one"

point=0

if user in list:
    
     point+=1

print(point)
```

Comment: please see [ask] a question and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

A list in Python is designed to contain multiple different elements, not just one. You can either redefine "one way or another" to be a string, without any list:

```
phrase = "one way or another"
user = "one"
point = 0
if user in phrase:
    point += 1
print(point)
```

Or you can iterate through each item in the list and check:

```
my_list = ["one way or another"]
user = "one"
point = 0
for item in my_list:
    if user in item:
        point += 1
print(point)
```

Edit:

It is bad practice to call your list `list`, as there is an inbuilt function of the same name. Instead it is better to use a name like `my_list` or `list1`.

Comment: So why dont you change the example accordingly?

Comment: I have done this now. The original intention was to deviate as little as possible from the asker's original code, especially considering that the asker identifies as a beginner. Using "list" as a variable name would still work, even if a not so great idea.